# How can I use await in the NodeJs terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I often start up the Node Js terminal to run small tasks or inspect some data. A current limitation is that I can't wait for an async function:

```sh
mymachine$ node
> const request = require('request-promise-native')
undefined
> await request('https://google.com')
Thrown:
await request('https://google.com')
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I end up having to do things like this

```
> let data;
undefined
> request('https://google.com').then(x => data = x)
Promise { <pending> }
> data.length
46262
```

but there are some inconveniences associated with this. Is there any other alternative so that I can chain a sequence of `await` commands in the node terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Via [this site](https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2018/whats-new-in-node-v10/):

Top Level Await is supported in Node version 10's REPL **if** you enable it with the `--experimental-repl-await` flag.

The official documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_await_keyword) and still requires the command line switch as of version 13.10.1.

Comment: That is beautiful. This makes my life so much easier

Comment: @Quentin Could we use IIFE to wrap await in async  ?

Comment: @Noob — That would be massively inconvenient when working in a REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it without declaring when starting the REPL

```
function testAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("This executed after 2 sec");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

let result;
(async function() {
  result = await testAsync();
  console.log(result);
})();
```